# Acts as taggable not adding tags with an angular form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, acts-as-taggable-on

I have an angular form that is creating an object with tags:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="createBeacon(beaconData)">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Tags</label>
  <div id="tags-list" data-current-user-company="{{current_user.company_id}}">
  <input type="text" id="tags-input" class="form-control" ng-model="beaconData.tag_list" name="beacon[tag_list]" placeholder="project, client 72, yellow, design"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

This form is submitting to a rails controller with a factory to commit to the database. Here is the function submitting the data:

```
$scope.createBeacon = function(beacon){
 Beacon.save({
  alias: beacon.alias,
  description: beacon.description,
  status: beacon.status,
  company_id: currentUser.company_id,
  venue_id: beacon.venue_id,
  beacon_id: beacon.beacon_id,
  tag_list: beacon.tag_list
 });
}
```

The result is the tag_list being passed as a parameter to to Rails as seen in the server log below but it does not commit into the tags and taggings tables as it would if being submitted with a Rails form.

[image: Tag Test 234]

Any suggestions on what to do here?

Comment: I don't see tag_list in the `beacon=> {}` hash.  It's one of the top level params, but I think it should be with the beacon specific values.

Comment: I believe that's part of the issue but I'm not sure why it wouldn't be in the hash along with the other parameters.

Comment: How is beaconData populated?

Comment: It takes the values from ng-model in the angular form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the strong parameters line from:

```
params.require(beacon).permit([:tag_list])
```

to:

```
params.permit([:tag_list])
```

fixed the issue of the tag_list not committing to the tags table. I know this is not preferable but it is the only solution I have found thus far.

Answer (score 0):

`"tag_list" => "Test 234"` in your request shows it is passed in as a text not an array. You need to make it pass as an array.

Also you need to make sure permitted_params to permit tag list as an array. 
`params.require(beacon).permit(tag_list: [])`

Comment: I tried this approach and it did not solve the problem.